# Exception inside CORBA when accessing a remote bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, javabeans, corba

On Windows Server with Glassfish 4.0 and JDK 1.7_55 I getting NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException then invoking remote bean methods.

```
StandardWrapperValve[action]: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBSingleton
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    ...
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
    at dudge.ifaces.__SolutionRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.getSolutionEager(dudge/ifaces/__SolutionRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    at dudge.ifaces._SolutionRemote_Wrapper.getSolutionEager(dudge/ifaces/_SolutionRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at dudge.DudgeBean.submitSolution(DudgeBean.java:119)
    ...
```

There DudgeBean and SolutionRemote are my classes.

And

```
StandardWrapperValve[action]: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.createInputStream(ValueHandlerImpl.java:820)
    ...
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
    at dudge.__PermissionCheckerRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.canGetUser(dudge/__PermissionCheckerRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    at dudge._PermissionCheckerRemote_Wrapper.canGetUser(dudge/_PermissionCheckerRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at dudge.web.actions.UsersAction.view(UsersAction.java:95)
    ...
```

There UsersActionand and PermissionCheckerRemote are my classes.

On development system everything works fine and I can't find a difference.
What could be causing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug related to JDK 1.7_55.
After downgrading to JDK 1.7_51 problem was solved.

There is an entry in the Glassfish bug tracker on this bug.
https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21047

Answer (score 1):

as @Aleksandr said, this is 7u55's bug.

You can try running glassfish with

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle ~/glassfish-3/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain domain1
```

This will temporary change JAVA_HOME path. Later you have to check localhost:4848 > srever > JVM report whether java root has changed. If it did not then you probably need to modify asadmin.conf script or domain.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a bug. I solved the same problem by upgradin JDK to 1.8.0_25