# CORBA exception in EJB application

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, ejb, marshalling, corba

I've got a problem with EJB/Glassfish. I'm working on a client-server application in which the client creates an entity object and must send it to the server application, which must persist the entity in its database. I've choose to use session beans to communicate with the server.
I've implemented some simple cases in which a method in the session bean takes as input a string or an int and it works fine. The problem arises when I try to give an entity object as input.

I report my entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Example implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
String nome;

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
```

Here my session bean:

```
 @Stateless
 public class GestoreLibreriaRemoto implements GestoreLibreriaRemotoRemote {

 @Override
 public String getProva(Example prova) {
    return prova.getNome();
 }
```

Here my client application:

```
public class GestoreLibreriaLocale {

public static void assegnaCategoriaACopia(CopiaUtente copia, Categoria categoria) throws 

public void prova() {
   GestoreLibreriaRemotoRemote gestore = lookupGestoreLibreriaRemotoRemote();
   Example example = new Example();
   prova.setNome("hodor");
   System.out.println(gestore.getProva(example));
}

private  GestoreLibreriaRemotoRemote lookupGestoreLibreriaRemotoRemote() {
    try {
        Context c = new InitialContext();
        return (GestoreLibreriaRemotoRemote) c.lookup("java:global/ServerMDB/ServerMDB-ejb/GestoreLibreriaRemoto");
    } catch (NamingException ne) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", ne);
        throw new RuntimeException(ne);
    }
}
```

In my main class I simply call GestoreLibreriaLocale.prova() and i get the following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.acc.AppClientContainer.launch(AppClientContainer.java:446)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.AppClientFacade.main(AppClientFacade.java:166)
    Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446346     Maybe; nested exception is: 
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: AVVERTENZA: 00810010: Error from readValue on ValueHandler in     CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 10 completed: Maybe
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy139.valuehandlerReadError(Unknown Source)
    at    com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:912)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1005)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:383)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readArguments(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:450)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:171)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.createInputStream(ValueHandlerImpl.java:820)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:263)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:903)
... 16 more
```

The error log continues, I don't report the whole log but if you need it I can post it. 
Please help me, I'm working on it from days without resolving it.
Thanks for the attention,
Francesco

Comment: Which JDK version have you installed (exact version number)?

Comment: In netbeans preferences is indicated JDK 1.8, executing java -version in the console the output is: java version "1.8.0_05"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the current Java versions (e.g. `1.7.0_55` and `1.8.0_05`), have a look at this issue: [GLASSFISH-21047](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21047)

To make it work, install either an older or a newer Java version (e.g. `1.7.0_051` or `1.8.0_020`).

**See also:**

- [Exception inside CORBA when accessing a remote bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291520/exception-inside-corba-when-accessing-a-remote-bean)

Comment: I've installed the jdk 1.7.0_051 but I get the same error

Comment: Did you make sure that GlassFish uses this JDK? You can set the JDK for the server runtime in NetBeans in the properties of your server runtime.

Comment: I'm getting the same error running JDK 1.8.0_25 and Glassfish 4.0 on OS X Yosemite.