# Using remote session bean in EJB to return entity results in Marshal Exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am using a remote session bean to return an entity in my managed bean, but it results in java.rmi.MarshalException as shown below.

```
Warning:   /login.xhtml @48,166 actionListener="#{AccountManagedBean.login}":
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446346 Maybe;   
nested exception  is: 
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810010: Error from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream
vmcid: OMG  minor code: 10 completed: Maybe javax.el.ELException: /login.xhtml @48,166 
actionListener="#   {AccountManagedBean.login}": javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException:
CORBA MARSHAL 1330446346
```

However, when i set the interface from @remote to @local to return the entity, it works perfectly fine. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628150/corba-exception-in-ejb-application. There is apparently a bug in JDK 1.7.0_55 and 1.8.0_05, can you try to downgrade your JDK?

Comment: Someone on https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21047 pointed that it should work with JDK 1.8.0_20. Please try to upgrade JDK and see if it works.