# What is the meaning of this ejb exception?

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb

I have tried to execute application which uses EJB and I've gotten this exception:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446346 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810010: Error from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 10 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy154.valuehandlerReadError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:912)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1005)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:383)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readArguments(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:450)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:171)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.createInputStream(ValueHandlerImpl.java:820)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:263)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:903)
    ... 16 more

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 10 completed: Maybe
```

Does anyone know, how to solve it?
I have glassfish 4 and jdk 1.7.0_60.

The code of application:

```
package com.apress.javaee6.chapter06;

import javax.ejb.*;

public class Main {
    
    @EJB
    private static BookEJBRemote bookEJB;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setTitle("The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy");
        book.setPrice(12.5F);
        book.setDescription("Scifi book created by Douglas Adams");
        book.setIsbn("1-84023-742-2");
        book.setNbOfPage(354);
        book.setIllustrations(false);
        
        bookEJB.createBook(book);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that your are facing [this bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21047) which is caused by **JDK 1.7_55** and **JDK 1.7_60**. To solve it you have to downgrade to **JDK 1.7_51**, install **JDK 8** or wait for a newer version of **JDK 7** which doesn't cause this bug.

Anyway, what you are trying to do is not possible in this way. You can't use `@EJB` in a plain java class (a class which is not managed by a container).

If you want to use a bean you have to retrieve it via JNDI. Have a look at the [GlassFish EJB FAQ](https://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html) to see how this is done.

**See also:**

- [Exception inside CORBA when accessing a remote bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291520/exception-inside-corba-when-accessing-a-remote-bean)
- [CORBA exception in EJB application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628150/corba-exception-in-ejb-application)

Comment: I installed JDK 8, but it's still that exception. I use Glassfish ACC to run application (appclient -client project.jar). So, the class should be  managed by container.
Thank you for reference, but i'd like to make this code work.